# Vanishing gradient and very low accuracy in InceptionV3

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm working on a multi-class classification using InceptionV3 using tensorflow.
I thought I got it all right, but the result is very weird and nowhere close to what I wanted.

```
Epoch 1/10
58/58 [==============================] - 47s 591ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0279
Epoch 2/10
58/58 [==============================] - 38s 591ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0286
Epoch 3/10
58/58 [==============================] - 38s 596ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0249
Epoch 4/10
58/58 [==============================] - 38s 603ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0250
```

Here is my code.

This chunk of code is where I deal with the data.
raw_train comes from oxford_iiit_pet.

```
dataset, metadata = tfds.load('oxford_iiit_pet', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
raw_train, raw_test = dataset['train'], dataset['test']
IMAGE_SIZE = (224, 224)


def preprocess_dataset(image, label):
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
  image = (image/127.5)-1 # might need to fix this part
  image = tf.image.resize(image, IMAGE_SIZE)
  return image, label

BATCH_SIZE = 64
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

train = raw_train.map(preprocess_dataset)
test = raw_test.map(preprocess_dataset)

train_batches = train.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_batches = test.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

This is my model.

```
IMG_SHAPE = (IMAGE_SIZE[0], IMAGE_SIZE[1], 3)
model_inception = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE, include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')

model_inception.trainable = False # freeze the model

learning_rate = 0.001

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    model_inception,
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=learning_rate),
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

EPOCHS = 10

history = model.fit(
    train_batches,
    epochs = EPOCHS
)
```

I'm not entirely sure if it's the way I preprocessed the data or the way I set up the model.
Everything seems fine until I actually run the model.
It seems like vanishing gradient that is happening but I don't know why and if it's actually the issue.
I've looked up to see how the model is used but nothing seems to give an answer clearly.

Answer (score 1):

So, you're outputting a single value that's in the domain of `[0.0,1.0]`.  But you say that there are multiple classes, not just one class: so you'll want to make the number of neurons in your last layer however many classes there are, and change it from a `sigmoid` activation to a `softmax` activation.  Like this:

```py
NUM_CLASSES = 8   # edit this number to suit your problem

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    model_inception,
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')
])
```

`sigmoid` won't work properly, even though it will *look* like it is (because all the values are floats between 0 and 1, just like `softmax` will give you).

Frankly I'm not even sure how you aren't getting some sort of error when calling `fit()`.  That's one of the problems with Keras, imho: it's so user friendly that it'll "work" (which is to say, *run*, not *work*) even when it should be giving you a hint about how you've set up your data improperly.  Unless the training targets in your training set consist of a single float value for every input image, it should not be even running.

Comment: Your last sentence is absolutely correct. I'm wondering if I should apply one hot encoding for that reason, but then there are some restrictions with that.